# Returning a promise instead of resolving it with angular's $q.then()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Suppose you have the following piece of code:

```
var callNo1 = $http(...).then(function (response1) {
    var callNo2 = $http(...).then(function (response2) {
        return [response1.data, response2.data];
    });

    return callNo2;
}).then(function (result) {
   console.log(result);
});
```

Since `callNo2` is a promise, an array of `[response1.data, response2.data]` will be logged to console. What I would like to achieve is to get the reference to `callNo2` promise instead. So my question would be: Is there a way to obtain a reference to inner promise through return statement so that it could be accessed through then argument.

P.S.

The following way would be considered as cheating:

```
var callNo1 = $http(...).then(function (response1) {
    var callNo2 = $http(...).then(function (response2) {
        return [response1.data, response2.data];
    });

    return { callNo2: callNo2 };
}).then(function (result) {
   console.log(['Do whatever required with result.callNo2', result.callNo2]);
});
```

Comment: You're asking if you can pull `callNo2` outside of the scope of `callNo1` and still have access to `response1`, even though you haven't brought it out of the scope as well.  So the answer is no.  There are certainly many ways to get the result you want, but you'd have to pass `response1` outside the scope (or into `callNo2`).

Comment: Maybe it is more appropriate to rephrase the question, is there a way to force $q not to resolve a promise with return statement

Comment: Sure, you can pass around promises just like anything else, and then chain onto them after they're received

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use callback function for this.Look:

```
function call1(callback){
    return $http(...).then(function (response1) {
        var callNo2 = $http(...).then(function (response2) {
            callback(response1.data, response2.data);
        });
    });
}

function calling(){
    call1(function(data1, data2){
        console.log(data1, data2);
    })
}
```

In then function of call1, run call2 and return promisse. When call2 is finish callback is called.

Comment: Thanks, you've gave me idea, I can resolve the closure function containing all the arguments I need... Thanks...!

Comment: this is a promise anti-pattern. No sense returning the promise and not using it

Comment: To whom do you refer to?

Comment: In my example, there was a return promise. I fixed this